# Retrieving data from a firebase database with multiple nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to retrieve the data from user and time. But I can't access the data, it's not really accessing the database.

[image]

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_balance);

    mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    cashRef=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("ASSETS").child("cash_at_bank");


    TextView view=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            cashRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    int time=dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);
                   int values =dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: it's `Cash at bank` not `cash_at_bank`

Comment: it's still not working it's giving me a null pointer    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()

Comment: obviously you have chids so get the child first

Comment: i tried but it' not working could you maybe show me

Answer (score 0):

To get the `time`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference cashAtBankRef = rootRef.child("ASSETS").child("Cash at bank");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Long time = ds.child("time").child("time").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d("TAG", time + "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
cashAtBankRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
150555043995
//and so on
```

Comment: thanks, i tried but it doesn't seem to be getting at the:                                                                                                                                          for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Integer time = ds.child("time").child("time").getValue(Integer.class);
            Log.d("TAG", time);
        }                                                                                                i used the Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: are you 1"); to see if it's getting here but it's not

Comment: What is the error? I have changed Integer with `Long`. Does it work now?

Comment: i tried it but the problem seems to be that it can't get to the for(){}   level

Comment: What does it mean you can't get the `for`? Should be executed. Try to debug using breakpoints

Comment: When you Log, what is printed?

Comment: i tried this way and some other way but it couldn't work,this is what i did: Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: the value is: "+value);  it gave me                 
  the value is: null

Comment: Have you changed your database structure somehow? I have tried this code and works 100%. Tru to use insead of `Log.d("TAG", time + "");` this `Log.d("TAG", ds + "");` Whhat does it print?